# How fix sd card unexpected unmounting on Lg L65 (kitkat)?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sd-card

I have bought sd card Kingstone  which supports UHS-I standart and use it with Lg L65 mobile phone (android 4.4.2). Of course I moved almost applications to it. Everything works just fine and **fast**, but every ~2 days I see a message that sd card was removed or has unsupported file system. I have to turn off (**not** restart) and turn on my mobile to make sd card working again.

Is there a way to fix such problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take out your SD card, then put it into your computer. In Windows, go in and check for errors. Then format the SD card, but make sure that you back up any information on the card that you do not want to lose

Comment: How to "check for errors"?